# Is there any way to find country code from phone number In php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find country code from the phone number because phone number is without country code(which is my input)
 for instance  my phone no is `9xxxxxxxxx` and I get result that number is from India and it will display then `+919xxxxxxxxx` in php.
Is there any way to find country code from phone number?

Comment: You need to set up a database of country codes - search the web, the data is freely available.  Then check whether your number starts with the code for whichever country - and that's your answer.  Start doing it, start writing code.  If you encounter specific issues with your code, then post again.

Comment: But how will he match the country code with the phone number if the number has just 10 digits and no country code attached with the phone number?

Comment: No There is no API or anything given for this purpose.You need to do this manually

Comment: I have doing this way as you ask and i have add one of the database for it.
and after enter one of the no and check with my database. in most of country maximum no of country code digit is 5. so i consider first five digit for check country code and if i added country code +919xxxxxxxxx, after i truncate it's country code and store on my one of the database table. it's working fine if user add like 9xxxxxxxxxx then in case if any country has one of the country code like 9x then as per my logic i was truncate country code so

Comment: 9x can be remove from my no and it will return like that xxxxxxxx so it will not proper, can you please suggest on it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_number_series_by_country i have use this link for country code reference

Answer (score 0):

First you'd need a source for the data listing every country, its code and the number of digits and pattern of the number.  Then you'd need to put that into an associative array, matching up each country with it's country code.  Then you'd need a bunch of preg_matches using regular expressions to determine if the first digits plus the regular expression matched the country in the array. You've talking a huge project to program this from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own PHP function for a lookup like this, a list of all the Phone Netnumbers can be found [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes). If there is no net number it's not possible to track the country since countries can use the same phone numbers.

Comment: I have got solution and we have to camper no from over database over this 9xxxxxxx no so it it will be find easily, Thanks to all.